# Upload file to EC2 which is behind cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, file-upload, amazon-cloudfront

I want to upload file to EC2. I am using ElasticBeanstalk to manage EC2 instance (it is using for CI/CD). So the chain is Cloudfront -> ElasticBeanstalk -> EC2. When I read data from request - I didn't see any data related with file. How to upload file to EC2 in such schema

**UPDATE:**
Nginx configuration, which Elasticbeanstalk added to EC2

```
location / {
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_http_version  1.1;

    proxy_set_header    Connection          $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

**UPDATE 2:** as I understand, this is not "aws (any cloud) way", I have to upload file to some extended storage, and then process it on the server. Because it help make app more scalable.

Comment: Maybe you didn't configure CloudFront properly to pass through all the data you need

Comment: What settings should I check? I set allow all HTTP methods, what else?

Comment: I don't thinks CF settings are the issue here. But you can make sure that you have **All viewer headers** enabled for your distribution's behaviour under origin request policy. Have you checked the nginx's settings for header forwarding?

Comment: BTW I am assuming that "I didn't see any data related with file." refers to missing headers...

Comment: I am using default ElasticBeanstalk configuration. Looks like it should be OK.

Comment: Thank you for everyone. I found where was the problem, shame on me, it was on the code, inside my nodejs app.